# ACTION_CALL not working on Kitkat

Tags: android, permissions

My application locks the screen and gives the option to make a call to some pre-defined numbers.

Here is the button listener to make the call

```
private final OnClickListener emergencycontact1listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        final String p = "tel:" + contact1;
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(p));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

The call phone permission was added to the manifest.

```
 android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```

This was all working prior to updating to KitKat 4.4 ... now , nothing happens, no attempt at calling and nothing in the logcat.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before ?

EDIT ---

OK, I know whats causing the problem, the default action for making a call hasnt been specified, if I enter the passcode, I am prompted to choose between skype and the dialer.

This "complete action" dosnt appear over the lock screen ... is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way given code also work on kitkat :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456"));           
startActivity(intent);
```

Note : add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```